# foreach loop in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I'm trying to loop over a request in the controller but i get this error:

`"Trying to get property 'produit_id' of non-object"`

here is the code

```
foreach( $request->livraison as $livraison) { 
   $produit = Produit::find($livraison->produit_id);
}
```

when i `dd($request->livraison)` i get this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "produit_id" => 1
    "quantite" => "43"
    "montant" => "65"
  ]
]
```

help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$livraison` is `array` not `object`

```
foreach( $request->livraison as $livraison)
{ 
        $produit = Produit::find($livraison['produit_id']);
}
```

Comment: I modified the code like this: `foreach( $request->livraison as $livraison) {
            $produit = Produit::find($livraison['produit_id']);
            $quantite = $produit->stock->quantite;
            $quantite += $livraison['quantite'];
        }` but the quantity does not change in the stock table. Any idea?

Comment: $produit->save(); -->save your $produit variable

Comment: I saved it but nothing changed.

Comment: your quantitly in produit table?

Comment: no. In stock table but in tryed saving both of produit and quantite variable

Comment: here is the code: `$produit = Produit::find($livraison['produit_id']); 
            $quantite = $produit->stock->quantite;
            $quantite += $livraison['quantite'];
            $quantite->save();`

Comment: i'm geting this error: `Call to a member function save() on integer`

Comment: $quantite is a only count quantities not a model reference

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array not a object so change your code to:

```
foreach( $request->livraison as $livraison) 
{ 
  $produit = Produit::find($livraison['produit_id']);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
$produit = Produit::find($livraison['produit_id']);
```